# Как правильнее дополнять справочник Django при деплое, если справочник может пополнятся пользователем во время работы системы

Tags: python, django

вопрос заключается в следующем

Упрощенно ситуация выглядит так:

Есть backend на Django, в Django описана модель справочника, в БД есть соотв. таблица.
В справочнике уже есть какой-то набор значений, например:

```
pk: 1; code: code1; name: name_code1
pk: 2; code: code2; name: name_code2
pk: 3; code: code3; name: name_code3
```

во время нормальной работы backend извне приходят доп. значения в справочник, им при создании выдаются pk, например:
pk: 4; code: code4; name: name_code4
pk: 5; code: code5; name: name_code5

теперь в справочнике:

```
pk: 1; code: code1; name: name_code1
pk: 2; code: code2; name: name_code2
pk: 3; code: code3; name: name_code3
pk: 4; code: code4; name: name_code4
pk: 5; code: code5; name: name_code5
```

во время разработки нового функционала со стороны команды появилась потребность дополнить справочник еще несколькими значениями, например:

```
pk: None; code: code6; name: name_code4
pk: None; code: code7; name: name_code5
```

(мы на этот момент не знаем какой последний pk был в справочнике, поэтому нельзя использовать фикстуры для такой загрузки)

когда новый функционал готов - необходимо его выложить на dev стенд, каким способом правильнее дополнять в таком случае справочник, чтобы новые записи (code: code6; code: code7) при деплое, после применения миграций и загрузки фикстур?

сейчас это реализовано так, есть yml файл в который вносятся значения,
при деплое выполняется запуск функции initial_data(), в которой происходит парсинг yml файла, в котором вписаны новые значения для справочника без pk, после парсинга файла - создаются записи через model_name.bulk_create()

хотелось бы понять, есть ли альтернативные способы, более правильные, возможно, что-то нативное от Django для этих целей или более адекватные решения этой задачи.

буду рад развернутым комментариям